# suspend the process execution up to displaying UI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have two UIs. I want my first UI to call a function and then have code to display the next UI, but the functions must start working after displaying the 2nd UI.

Comment: hmm .. not the clearest of questions, but why downvoting - without explaining what's deemed wrong? Upvote for balance :-)

Comment: So what exactly is wrong now ? Aren't you able to show your **Second User Interface** before the control jumps to the function call ? Please edit your question to put more information.

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark here - you might want to look into [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).